# Fisheye can't clone git repo

Tags: git, atlassian-fisheye

I set up Fisheye and can't establish the connection to git server. Could anybody help me?

Error in log:

> 2015-09-16 21:34:28,316 WARN  [InitPing1 hornet ] fisheye IndexingPingRequest-doRequest - Exception during FishEye Incremental
>   Indexing of git: com.cenqua.fisheye.config.ConfigException: Unable to
>   clone remote repository: ssh://git@192.168.2.90/src.git - [Cloning
>   into bare repository 'clone'..., Could not create directory
>   '/home/\321\201\320\270\321\201\321\202\320\265\320\274\320\260/.ssh'.,
>   FATAL: invalid repo name: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/src', fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository., , Please make sure you have
>   the correct access rights, and the repository exists.]

Fisheye ssh key was added on server, ssh binary was found. What is wrong?

Comment: This error is  related to ssh configuration on your computer. Seems like FishEye considers your OS be an Unix-like OS (e.g. Linux) and tries to create _ssh_ configuration files in the path that would correct if your OS was Linux, but obviously incorrect for MS Windows.

Comment: I would search if there's a possibility to configure FishEye such a way that would allow to specify where SSH configuration should reside (smth like `C:\Documents and Settings\your_name\.ssh`)